# Игра змейка, проблема реализации

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр

Начал писать консольную змейку, сталкивался с многими проблемами, но данную проблему не могу пока что решить. Проблема в том, что как только игра начинается всё в порядке, края правильно рисуются, но стоит взять фрукт так сразу происходит какая-то ахинея и правая сторона уходит на несколько клеточек вправо.

```
import threading
import random
import os
from pynput import keyboard
from time import sleep


def draw():
    global score
    global fruitX
    global fruitY
    global snake

    os.system("clear")

    # top
    for i in range(0, width + 1):
        print("#", end='')
    print()

    # all mid
    for i in range(0, height):
        for j in range(0, width):
            if (j == 0) or (j == width - 1):
                print("#", end='')
            for k in snake:
                if (i == k[1]) and (j == k[0]):
                    print("G", end='')
                elif (i == fruit[0][1]) and (j == fruit[0][0]):
                    print('*', end='')
                else:
                    print(' ', end='')
        print()

    # bot
    for i in range(0, width + 1):
        print("#", end='')
    print()

    print(f"Total score: {score}")


def input():
    with keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()


def on_release(key):
    global gameOver
    global snake

    ka = 0

    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        gameOver = True

    if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('w'):
        for k in snake:
            snake[ka][1] -= 1
        ka += 1

    if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('s'):
        for k in snake:
            snake[ka][1] += 1
        ka += 1

    if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('d'):
        for k in snake:
            snake[ka][0] += 1
        ka += 1

    if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('a'):
        for k in snake:
            snake[ka][0] -= 1
        ka += 1


def logic():
    global score
    global fruit
    global snake

    # Got a fruit
    if (snake[0][0] == fruit[0][0]) and (snake[0][1] == fruit[0][1]):
        score += 1
        snake.append([snake[0][0] - 1, snake[0][1]])
        fruit.pop()

    if len(fruit) == 0:
        fruit.append((random.randint(1, width - 1),
                      random.randint(1, height - 1)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gameOver = False
    width = 20
    height = 20

    snake = [[width / 2 - 1,
              height / 2 - 1]]

    fruit = [(random.randint(1, width - 1),
              random.randint(1, height - 1))]
    score = 0

    t_input = threading.Thread(target=input, name='InputThread')
    t_input.start()

    # Main game
    while not gameOver:
        sleep(0.1)
        draw()
        logic()
```

Можете не кидать готовый код, можно просто объяснить что не так. Если всё уж так плохо, то подскажите что переучить заново, или попрактиковаться снова. Учился по книге Билл Любанович "Простой Python"
[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Змея это `G`, а фрукт -- `*`?

Comment: @gil9red именно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> но стоит взять фрукт так сразу происходит какая-то ахинея и правая
> сторона уходит на несколько клеточек вправо

Смотрите, у вас когда рисуется змейка заодно рисуются фрукт и пустое пространство, что странно - это ведь разные объекты.

```
...

        for k in snake:
            if (i == k[1]) and (j == k[0]):
                print("G", end='')
            elif (i == fruit[0][1]) and (j == fruit[0][0]):
                print('*', end='')
            else:
                print(' ', end='')

...
```

Поэтому, когда змейка берет фрукт, у змеи становится два блока и тот цикл два раза прогоняется и получается в два раза больше пространства

---

Решил другим подходом рисовать поле - сначала составить матрицу, заполнить ее, а после отрисовать:

```
import threading
import random
import os
from pynput import keyboard
from time import sleep


def clear():
    if os.name == 'posix':
        os.system('clear')
    else:
        os.system('cls')


def draw():
    global score
    global snake

    board = []
    for _ in range(width):
        board.append([' ' for _ in range(height)])

    # Top
    for i in range(width):
        board[0][i] = "#"

    # Left
    for i in range(height):
        board[i][0] = "#"

    # Right
    for i in range(height):
        board[i][width - 1] = "#"

    # All mid
    for i, j in snake:
        board[j][i] = 'G'

    for i, j in fruit:
        board[j][i] = '*'

    # Bottom
    for i in range(width):
        board[height - 1][i] = "#"

    clear()
    print()

    for row in board:
        print(''.join(row))

    print(f"Total score: {score}")


def keyboard_listener():
    with keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()


def on_release(key):
    global gameOver
    global snake

    ka = 0

    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        gameOver = True

    if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('w') or key == keyboard.Key.up:
        for k in snake:
            snake[ka][1] -= 1
        ka += 1

    if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('s') or key == keyboard.Key.down:
        for k in snake:
            snake[ka][1] += 1
        ka += 1

    if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('d') or key == keyboard.Key.right:
        for k in snake:
            snake[ka][0] += 1
        ka += 1

    if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('a') or key == keyboard.Key.left:
        for k in snake:
            snake[ka][0] -= 1
        ka += 1


def logic():
    global score
    global fruit
    global snake

    print(f'snake={snake} fruit={fruit}')

    # Got a fruit
    if snake[0][0] == fruit[0][0] and snake[0][1] == fruit[0][1]:
        score += 1
        snake.append([snake[0][0] - 1, snake[0][1]])
        fruit.pop()

    if not fruit:
        fruit.append((random.randint(1, width - 1),
                      random.randint(1, height - 1)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gameOver = False
    width = 20
    height = 20

    snake = [[width // 2 - 1, height // 2 - 1]]

    fruit = [(random.randint(1, width - 1), random.randint(1, height - 1))]
    score = 0

    t_input = threading.Thread(target=keyboard_listener, name='InputThread')
    t_input.start()

    # Main game
    while not gameOver:
        draw()
        logic()

        sleep(0.1)
```

---

**PS.**

Вам нужно будет подумать как движение змейки организовать, пока только голова движется

**PPS**

Этот код с этим может выдать странный результат

```
snake = [[width / 2 - 1, height / 2 - 1]]
```

`/` - это деление с остатком, после него будет вещественное число. Поэтому, нужно делить через `//`

Comment: Вопросик. Так-то я всё понял, но как работает `for i, j in snake:...`? Я просто не встречал такой записи, чтобы в `for` сразу две переменные счётчики

Comment: @Ker1an, у вас в `snake` лежат списки по два элемента. Питон умеет раскладывать коллекции (списки, кортежи, строки и т.п.) на переменные. Например, `n = [1, 2]` `a, b = n`. Так что, в for на каждой итерации возвращается список на два элемента и тут же раскладывается на переменные i и j